# C++ Builder Flow Diagram Component?

Tags: c++builder, vcl, flow-diagram

We want to draw large control flow diagrams in a C++ builder XE application being developed.

These diagrams will be generated programaticaly and displayed to the user in an interactive fashion (the user can scroll around the large flow diagram, select nodes and so on). The nodes must be capable of displaying a custom component (Like a TCanvas). Speed in displaying very large diagrams is important and extras like anti-aliasing are a good bonus.

Ideally we would like a native c++ builder/delphi VCL component for this but may fall back to an ActiveX controll or similar if we have to. We would require a source license to any component if its a commercial component/library but will happily consider free/open source components too.

Currently the following 2 components were found but are activex controls:

- MindFusion FlowChartX - http://www.mindfusion.eu/download.html - Currently this is the best I have found.
- Lassalle AddFlow ActiveX - http://www.lassalle.com/features.htm - This component is outdated (last version around 2007) and not as polished as the above option.

Can anybody recommend any suitable solutions for programatically creating and drawing interactive flow diagrams?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

TMS Software Diagram Studio is native VCL and might do what you need. It can be found here for about € 95:

[TMS Diagram Studio](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/diagram.asp)

Further more there is ExpressFlowChart from DevExpress for around: $ 90, it is also native VCL and can be found here:

[ExpressFlowChart](http://devexpress.com/Products/VCL/ExFlowChart/)

I don't have any experience with either of these components, but have used components from both vendors before, and have generally liked the quality they have provided. DevExpress seems really professional in my opinion.

Comment: thanks, both good suggestions. I will evaluate them and post back my findings at a later stage.